# C #Работа с файлами

Tags: c#

Исходный файл состоит из строк, в каждой из которых записаны данные о книге в следующем порядке:

- Название книги
- Фамилия И.О. автора
- Год выпуска
- Издательство
- Тираж
- Количество страниц

Вопрос: Для заданного издательства записать в выходной файл данные об авторах, которые публиковались в этом издательстве в виде:

- Фамилия И.О. автора
- Количество опубликованных книг

Comment: В чем проблема заключается?

Comment: На данном ресурсе не принято решать задание за автора, здесь принято помогать в решении.

Comment: Это не вопрос, а, скорее, завуалированная просьба в выполнении задачи за автора...

Answer (score 2):

алгоритм может быть например таким:

1. Читаем/десереализуем исходный файл в некий *объект*;
2. При помощи `Where()` получаем книги необходимого издательства;
3. Делаем группировку по автору `GroupBy()`;
4. Для каждой группы получаем количество;

---

Создадим класс для дальнейшей работы

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Author {get;set;}
    public DateTime DateOfPublication {get;set;}
    public string Publisher {get;set;}
    public int Сirculation {get;set;}
    public int NumberOfPages {get;set;}
}

var books = //читаем/десериализуем исходный файл сюда

var result = books.Where(x=>x.Publisher.Equals("Необходимое издательство"))
                  .GroupBy(x=>x.Author)
                  .Select(x=> new {Author = x.Key, CountOfPublishedBooks = x.Count()})
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Пугаем новичков лямбда функциями =)

Comment: ну почему же пугаем, я задал *вектор движения* для решения